# Image from camera is null if camera is rotated

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-camera

I am showing a picker to the user to choose between Gallery or Camera to select a photo. If I choose Camera, then once camera has loaded I rotate to take a Landscape photo, take the photo and click done, it returns to my app but the returned image is null.
If I don't rotate the camera, the image is returned fine.
What am I missing?
I know the rotation causes the Activity to be rebuilt, but why wouldn't the onActivityResult contain the right information?
Here is my openImage Intent:

```
public void openImageIntent() {

        // Determine Uri of camera image to save.
        final File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "MyAppImages"
                + File.separator);
        root.mkdirs();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyy-hhmmss");
        final String fname = String.format("%s.jpg", sdf.format(new Date()));
        final File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, fname);
        outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);

        // Camera.
        final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
        final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
        for (ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
            final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
            final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
            intent.setPackage(packageName);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
            cameraIntents.add(intent);
        }

        // Filesystem.
        final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
        galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
        galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

        // Chooser of filesystem options.
        final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Select Source");

        // Add the camera options.
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[] {}));

        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, SELECT_PICTURE_REQUEST);
    }
```

And the onActivityResult method:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE_REQUEST) {
                final boolean isCamera;
                if (data == null) {
                    isCamera = true;
                } else {
                    final String action = data.getAction();
                    if (action == null) {
                        isCamera = false;
                    } else {
                        isCamera = true;
                    }
                }

                Uri selectedImageUri;
                if (isCamera) {
                    selectedImageUri = outputFileUri;
                } else {
                    selectedImageUri = data == null ? null : data.getData();
                }

                if (imageDelegate != null) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "imageDelegate not null: " + imageDelegate);
                    imageDelegate.gotNewImageUri(selectedImageUri);
                    imageDelegate = null;

                } else if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("addofferdialog") != null) {
                    imageDelegate = (AddOfferFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("addofferdialog");
                    Log.e(TAG, "imageDelegate is null but found fragment: " + imageDelegate);
                    Log.e(TAG, "Activity image: " + selectedImageUri);
                    imageDelegate.gotNewImageUri(selectedImageUri);
                    imageDelegate = null;
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "cannot find imageDelegate!!!!");
                }

             Log.e(TAG, "selectedImageUri: " + selectedImageUri);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to change your manifest file

in your manifest just replace below code

```
<activity android:name=".CameraTestActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"     android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
```

with your code

```
<activity android:name=".CameraTestActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Comment: Wow, that was easy. Thanks

Comment: Had to wait 10 minutes before I could.

Answer (score 3):

Just save `outputFileUri`  in [onSaveInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29)  and restore it in [onRestoreInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) other wise it will be null in orientation change.

Comment: Thank you. This works but I found the Manifest change to be far simpler as it keeps the Activity intact.

Comment: You should anyway try to save the data for orientation changes.

Comment: @Darren ya it is easy but you have to do the above to make sure that your app doesnt crash in other situations like... activity destroyed in background for memory

Comment: This is the better answer. As changing the manifest in a more complex app is not a viable option.

Answer (score 1):

This Worked well for me..

```
<activity
    android:name=".CameraTestActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden">
</activity>
```